# Circular Dependency caused without import?

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers, python-import, circular-dependency

Code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/pull/40/files).

I have created a file, [results_pb2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/blob/635595df47a24154e7c2330e58804c7165a3d372/tcav/results_pb2.py). I then had [utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/blob/635595df47a24154e7c2330e58804c7165a3d372/tcav/utils.py) import this file.

However, when I try to run [utils_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/blob/635595df47a24154e7c2330e58804c7165a3d372/tcav/utils_test.py), I get a circular dependency. For some reason, results_pb2.py is calling another Python program, [tcav.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/blob/635595df47a24154e7c2330e58804c7165a3d372/tcav/tcav.py) that depends on utils.py through a chain of dependencies. Here is the full chain / stack trace below:

```
File "/usr/local/home/karanshukla/tcav/tcav/utils_test.py", line 19, in <module>
  from tcav.utils import flatten, process_what_to_run_expand, process_what_to_run_concepts, process_what_to_run_randoms
File "tcav/utils.py", line 20, in <module>
  from tcav.results_pb2 import Result, Results
File "tcav/tcav.py", line 22, in <module>
  from tcav.cav import CAV
File "tcav/cav.py", line 27, in <module>
  from tcav import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

The bizarre thing is that *I don't see tcav.py being imported by results_pb2.py*. I would appreciate if someone could explain what is causing this unexpected import.

For reference, below are the imports in results_pb2.py:

```
import sys
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
```

---

To reproduce the bug, install the [protoc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.9.1) tool (for generating results_pb2.py), pull the codebase from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tcav/pull/40), and run the following commands:

```
pip uninstall tcav
rm tcav/results_pb2.pyc tcav/results_pb2.py
protoc tcav/results.proto --python_out=.
python setup.py bdist_wheel --python-tag py2
pip install dist/tcav-0.2.1-py2-none-any.whl
python -m tcav.utils_test
```

Comment: The error messages suggests that line 22 of the `utils` module is `from tcav.cav import CAV`. That doesn't seem to be the case in the code you linked. Is it that way in your code? Looking at the linked code, you appear to be dealing with serialized data, and I suspect that what is happening is that the deserialization process requires that modules be imported (`pickle` does this, I'm not sure if that's what your library code is using or not). Perhaps you could store the serialized data only, and unserialize them in some other module where the import won't be circular?

Comment: Yep, for some reason the `protoc` serialization was dependent on all the code inside of my module. Moving `results_proto` and `results_pb2.py` into a new module, and importing that module into `utils.py`, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the `protoc` serialization taking the entire `tcav` module as a dependency. Moving `results.proto` outside of the `tcav` module and into a new, separate `tcav_results` module fixed the issue.

This doesn't seem ideal. But, it gets around the issue of a circular dependency caused by serializing with `protoc`.